# pandas installation fails on git push dokku master

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm trying to deploy an app on Digital Ocean, droplet being Ubuntu 14.04 with Dokku, 512mb RAM, app is Flask with Postgres. The installation seems to fail when pandas is installed, but I don't really understand what could cause it. What can I do to troubleshoot it?

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ociGjE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /opt/app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Right now I tried adding swap to droplet, maybe memory was the issue, will report as soon as done

Comment: Solved, adding 256mb swapfile was enough